# caffeine-indicator error

Tags: caffeine

I have this error when I try to start caffeine

/usr/bin/caffeine-indicator:29: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
import pkg_resources

Anyone know how can I solved?
Thanks

Comment: Probably from htm:  https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html